# QM : Perturbation theory with multiple operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

When doing perturbation theory in quantum mechanics, if the perturbation hamiltonian is made of three terms :
$$W = W_1 +W_2 + W_3,$$
can I treat each term separately and performing perturbation theory for each one of them, then adding the perturbed energies together to get the total energy ?

$$ E \stackrel{?}{=} E^0 + E_1^1 +E_2^1 +E_3^1 $$
where $E^0$ is the energy of the unperturbed hamiltonian, and $E^1_j$'s are energies at first order of $W_j$'s.

Edit : What about degenerate perturbation theory ?

Comment: To the first order,this is correct. All the cross terms will come with 2nd order or higher.

Comment: I guess you can parametrize the perturbation as $W=\lambda_1 W_1 + \lambda_2 W_2 + \lambda_3 W_3$ and $E= \sum_{n_1,n_2,n_3} \lambda_1^{n_1}  \lambda_2^{n_2}  \lambda_3^{n_3} E_{n_1,n_2,n_3}$

Comment: I fear it may not work in the case of degenerate perturbation theory... I will have to diagonalise the Hamiltonian in the degenerate subspace. It is easy if I do it for each $W_j$ separately, but the $W$ is difficult to diagonalise. And I don't see how separating the $W$ in terms can yields the correct answer.